# How long should I work somewhere for putting them in my resume

Tags: resume, software

I am fresh out of university and in 1 year, I have been working at two different companies. The last one is recent (3-4 months) and it does not seem like a good fit. Should I put that experience in my resume ?

More general, what is the minimal amount of time I need to work somewhere before putting it in my resume.

Additionnal info: I finished electrical engineering, but spent 10 months working in a software company, and currently in an industry where I do electrical and software  work. I would like to focus more into software, since it fits more my interests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am fresh out of university and in 1 year, I have been working at two different companies.

You should list all the relevant work you've done. You've only been out of school for a year, so it's surely better to include a job that gave you 3 or 4 months of experience than to have a gap that long.

Employers are sometimes concerned if it looks like someone has a habit of jumping from one job to another after only a few months because that kind of pattern can mean either that the previous employers have been unhappy with the candidate, or that the candidate might be more likely to jump to a different job after a short time. Even without a long string of short stints, if you're leaving the job you have after only a few months, you should expect to get some questions about why.

But none of that is disqualifying. Just be honest, be prepared to talk about the positions you've had, and avoid badmouthing your past employers.